# App crashing from too many Async Tasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download about 150 images for an application upgrade package.

There are in total about 400 files that need to be downloaded from Firebase Storage.

I have it mostly set up fine and it's working okay except when it comes to downloading the images which my code submits a huge amount of them rapidly.

It seems I'm putting too many requests for new Async tasks and I'm getting this error:

```
threadpoolexecutor@3ae67af[running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 9]
```

This is the code I'm using to download the images:

```
for (int x = 0; x < poi.size(); x++) {
        if (x < poi.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < poi.get(x).achievement.size(); i++) {
                final String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(poi.get(x).achievement.get(i), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
                for (int p = 0; p < (poi.get(x).numberOfAchievementPhoto.get(i)); p++) {
                    new POIImageDownloader(normalized, p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have seen in other posts that I should use something like an `ArrayBlockingQueue` to achieve this but I have no idea how to implement it in this situation due to my newbness.

I have tried adding a `Thread.sleep` but that shuts off my UI from updating and would make the user think the app has crashed.

I could do something messy like breaking it up into smaller chunks and only calling another batch from the firebase `onSuccess` method but that is just messy.

Is there any clean way to download all of these images without all the stress?